# Second Lowest value from another table after join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, hive

I need help to solve this specific sql problem, i can't write stored procs as i need to port this to Hive.

There are two tQCles Contr and Lvl and i need to left join them and populate the null values from LVL in the joined tQCle with values from previous row.
 I have the sample tQCles in

```
Contr
|      id |     EFF_DT | M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR | L_CD |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|------|
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 |  POT |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            2 |  POT |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            3 |  POT |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            2 |  MIC |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            4 |  MIC |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            2 |  POT |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            3 |  POT |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            4 |  POT |
| ACB3DC2 | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1 |  POT |

LVL
|      id |     EFF_DT | M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR | OCCR |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|------|
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 |  100 |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            3 |  100 |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            2 |  200 |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            3 |  200 |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1 |    0 |

LEFT JOIn of Contr and Lvl

|      id |     EFF_DT | M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR | L_CD |      id |     EFF_DT |  M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR |   OCCR |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|------|---------|------------|--------|--------------|--------|
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 |  POT | QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |     11 |            1 |    100 |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            2 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            3 |  POT | QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |     11 |            3 |    100 |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            2 |  MIC | QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |     00 |            2 |    200 |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            4 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            2 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            3 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            4 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
| ACB3DC2 | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |       (null) | (null) |
```

Now I need to populate the values for empty ACTY_SEQ_NBR from LVl tQCle with values. 
The criteria is , find the corresponding ACTY_SEQ_NBR from CONTR (i.e from column 4 of joined tQCle) and find the ACTY_SEQ_NBR from LVL where the ACTY_SEQ_NBR is less 
than or equal to the value from CONTR ACTY_SEQ_NBR for same id, eff_dt and m_nbr.

for. e.g Row#2 has null ACTY_SEQ_NBR.Its corresponding Contr ACTY_SEQ_NBR is 2, the ACTY_SEQ_NBR value which is less than 2  from LVL is 1.

So my ideal output should be like  for this row.

```
|      id |     EFF_DT | M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR | L_CD |      id |     EFF_DT |  M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR |   OCCR |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|------|---------|------------|--------|--------------|--------|
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 |  POT | QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |     11 |            1 |    100 |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            2 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |            1 | (null) |

I tried a lag query but its not giving correct output for all values.
```

I executed Amniders query and i changed the results to get expected values.
Here is my expected values

```
|      ID |     EFF_DT | M_NBR | ACTY_SEQ_NBR | L_CD |  LVL_ID | LVL_EFF_DT | LVL_M_NBR | LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR |   OCCR | CALC_LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|------|---------|------------|-----------|------------------|--------|-----------------------|
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 |  POT | QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |        11 |                1 |    100 |                     1 |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            2 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                     1 |
| QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            3 |  POT | QQFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |        11 |                3 |    100 |                     3 |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            2 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                     1 |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            3 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                     1 |
| QC56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            4 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                     1 |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                   -99 |
| QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            2 |  MIC | QCC5433 | 2013-04-21 |        00 |                2 |    200 |                     2 |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            1 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                   -99 |
| QCC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            4 |  MIC |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                     3 |
| ACB3DC2 | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1 |  POT |  (null) |     (null) |    (null) |           (null) | (null) |                   -99 |
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for more extensive examples!  This might be do-able with a single full outer join, but I think the aggregation and filtering would get messy.  Simplest bet is to left join to lvl twice, first to find the "previous act_seq_nbr", and then again as you have been (but using coalesce to use "previous act_seq_nbr" when no act_seq_nbr is found):

```
SELECT  c.id,c.eff_dt,c.m_nbr,c.acty_seq_nbr, 
        l.id,l.eff_dt,l.m_nbr,
        coalesce(l.acty_seq_nbr, prev_acty_seq_nbr, -99) l_acty_seq_nbr
from 
    (       
    select c.id,c.eff_dt,c.m_nbr,c.acty_seq_nbr, 
           MAX(L.acty_seq_nbr) prev_acty_seq_nbr
    from   contr c 
    left join lvl l 
        on 
            c.id=l.id 
            and c.eff_dt=l.eff_dt 
            and c.m_nbr=l.m_nbr 
            and c.acty_seq_nbr>l.acty_seq_nbr
    GROUP BY   
        c.id,c.eff_dt,c.m_nbr,c.acty_seq_nbr
    ) c
left join lvl l 
    on 
        c.id=l.id 
        and c.eff_dt=l.eff_dt 
        and c.m_nbr=l.m_nbr     
        and c.acty_seq_nbr=l.acty_seq_nbr;
```

Fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1270f/74/0

Results:

```
|      id |     eff_dt | m_nbr | acty_seq_nbr |      id |     eff_dt |  m_nbr | l_acty_seq_nbr |
|---------|------------|-------|--------------|---------|------------|--------|----------------|
| AAFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            1 | AAFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |     11 |              1 |
| AAFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            2 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |              1 |
| AAFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |    11 |            3 | AAFAE46 | 2000-12-24 |     11 |              3 |
| AB56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            2 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |              1 |
| AB56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            3 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |              1 |
| AB56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            4 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |              1 |
| ABC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            1 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |            -99 |
| ABC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 |            2 | ABC5433 | 2013-04-21 |     00 |              2 |
| ABC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            1 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |            -99 |
| ABC614E | 2015-07-18 |    00 |            4 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |              3 |
| ACB3DC2 | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1 |  (null) |     (null) | (null) |            -99 |
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but the query is not working as expected. MAX is not the one I need, if theACTY_SEQ  value of LVL table join are null , find the ACTY_SEQ value from LVL table which is less than the ACTY_SEQ value of the corresponding CONTR table.

Comment: I'm with Amninder - can you provide edit original question with sample data that actually demonstrates all variations (and desired results of each)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
     ID, EFF_DT, M_NBR, ACTY_SEQ_NBR, L_CD, LVL_ID, LVL_EFF_DT, LVL_M_NBR, LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR, OCCR
   ,COALESCE(CASE WHEN LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR IS NULL THEN COALESCE(LAG(ACTY_SEQ_NBR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, EFF_DT, M_NBR ORDER BY ACTY_SEQ_NBR),ACTY_SEQ_NBR) ELSE LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR END,'NA') LVL_NMBR
    FROM(
    SELECT A.ID, A.EFF_DT, A.M_NBR, A.ACTY_SEQ_NBR, A.L_CD
    , B.ID LVL_ID, B.EFF_DT LVL_EFF_DT, B.M_NBR LVL_M_NBR, B.ACTY_SEQ_NBR LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR , B.OCCR
    FROM EDWT.CONTR A
    LEFT JOIN EDWT.LVL B
    ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.ACTY_SEQ_NBR = B.ACTY_SEQ_NBR and a.eff_dt=b.eff_dt and a.m_nbr=b.m_nbr ) A;
```

Also, please help with the valid value for the following rows:

> ID    EFF_DT  M_NBR   ACTY_SEQ_NBR    L_CD    LVL_ID  LVL_EFF_DT  LVL_M_NBR   LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR    OCCR    LVL_NMBR
>
> ABC5433   2013-04-21  00  1   IMC 1

what data are you expecting for lvl_acty_seq_nbr for ABC614E & ABC5433. ABC614E doesn't has acty_Seq_nbr in lvl table and has 1 & 4in contr. Please provide your expected output for above id. Do you want a lowest value within same id or lowest from all ids?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am able to understand your problem. Try this query:

```
 SELECT
 ID, EFF_DT, M_NBR, ACTY_SEQ_NBR, L_CD, LVL_ID, LVL_EFF_DT, LVL_M_NBR, LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR, OCCR
 --,LAG(ACTY_SEQ_NMBR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, EFF_DT, M_NBR ORDER BY ACTY_SEQ_NMBR)
 ,COALESCE(CASE WHEN LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR IS NULL THEN LAG(ACTY_SEQ_NBR) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, EFF_DT, M_NBR ORDER BY ACTY_SEQ_NBR) ELSE LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR END,'NA') CALC_LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR    FROM(
SELECT A.ID, A.EFF_DT, A.M_NBR, A.ACTY_SEQ_NBR, A.L_CD
, B.ID LVL_ID, B.EFF_DT LVL_EFF_DT, B.M_NBR LVL_M_NBR, B.ACTY_SEQ_NBR LVL_ACTY_SEQ_NBR , B.OCCR
FROM EDWT.CONTR A
LEFT JOIN EDWT.LVL B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.ACTY_SEQ_NBR = B.ACTY_SEQ_NBR and a.eff_dt=b.eff_dt and a.m_nbr=b.m_nbr ) A;
```

Comment: Thank Amninder for the try, but not getting expected results.  The query fails in case of Row#4 ABC5433 | 2013-04-21 |    00 | 1  where LVL data are all null, we need to find the lowest ACTY_SEQ from LVL. w.r.t to a value lower or equal to its CONTR value. As per the query it return 'NA' even though we have an LVL entry.                            AB56DDF | 1999-10-01 |    14 |            1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on how you want to handle the examples that are outside of the two lines you provided...  if you can fill in the blanks for the rest of the data, that would help.

In the meantime, here's a crack at it:

```
with foo as (
  select
    c.id as cid, c.eff_dt as c_eff_dt,
    c.m_nbr as c_m_nbr, c.acty_seq_nbr as c_acty_seq_nbr,
    l.id as lid, l.eff_dt as l_eff_dt, l.m_nbr as l_m_nbr,
    l.acty_seq_nbr as l_acty_seq_nbr,
    sum (case when l.id is null then 0 else 1 end)
      over (partition by c.id order by c.acty_seq_nbr) as idx
  from
    contr c
    left join lvl l on
      c.id=l.id and 
      c.eff_dt=l.eff_dt and 
      c.m_nbr=l.m_nbr and 
      c.acty_seq_nbr=l.acty_seq_nbr
)
select
  cid, c_eff_dt, c_m_nbr, c_acty_seq_nbr,
  lid, l_eff_dt, l_m_nbr, l_acty_seq_nbr,
  min (c_acty_seq_nbr) over (partition by cid, idx) as acty_seq_nbr
from foo
```

Comment: Thanks Hambone. I will explain a bit more . After we do a LEFT join on Contr c and LVL l , we will get null values for l.id,l.eff_dt, l.m_nbr and l.seq_nbr . For all the rows having null for LVL l, we need to populate l.acty_seq_nbr values from LVL table. For that the condition is find the  a.id,a.eff_dt, a.m_nbr of the Left Joined table and for the value of a.acty_seq_nbr find a lower or equal value from LV table like (SELECT nl.acty_seq_nbr from LVL nl where a.id=nl.id and a.eff_dt=nl.eff_dt and a.m_nbr=nl.m_nbr and nl.acty_seq_nbr <= a.acty_seq_nbr ) . Hope this helps